# Questions related to NodeJS API and Java API

Tags: rest

1. If I want to develop a Create, Read, Update, Delete (CRUD) system, what should I consider when choosing an API?
2. What are the pros and cons of NodeJS API and Java API?
3. Why NodeJS's single thread can make servers more scalable than multi-thread?
4. What databases can be accessed using Java API's Java Database Connectivity?
5. What are the similarities between NodeJS API and Java API?

Answer (score 0):

1. I think the best choose for API for your CRUD development is depends on what type of your application. if you want a fast and reliable app, you should choose node.js for your API. But if you can ignore that and want to more like advance feature, you can pick java for your API.
2. Pros in NodeJS compare to Java API are Asynchronous, Very fast, and highly scalable. Cons in NodeJS compare to Java API are not suitable for CPU-intensive task, hard to operate when using relational database, and doesn't provide scalability.
3. Because single threaded have advantage such as can handle many client with ease, eliminate the need of more thread because of the event loop, and use the least threads to reduce memory and resource usage.
4. Oracle and MySQL.
5. About similarities we think Java API can do what NodeJS do but NodeJS can do all what Java API can do.